# How to check if a model can make phone calls?

Tags: calls, tablet, sim-card

So I'm looking to buy a new android tablet, but I can not for the life of me find out for any given tablet whether or not it can make and receive phone calls like a regular android phone would.
Am I correct that just because something has a possibility for a SIM card, it can't automatically make phone calls too?

Comment: You are correct, there are data-only SIMs.  You should look at the technical specifications on the manufacturer's website or somewhere like http://www.gsmarena.com/.

Comment: Which part of the technical specs in GSMArena shows me this info, because as far as I know, it is not listed there.